# a two high-rises

Tags: articles

> The project called The George, would feature **a two high-rises** with
>   a 118-room hotel, a conference centre, and 35 luxury condominiums.

[Gibsons split over proposed hotel and condo development](http://www.cbc.ca/news/canada/british-columbia/gibsons-split-over-proposed-hotel-and-condo-development-1.3254287)

Is this right?  Or is it supposed to be "**two high-rises**" or "**a building with two high-rises** "?

Comment: "We don't use A/AN with possessive pronouns, demonstratives or **[cardinal numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinal_number)**." So it must be a typo..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a typo in the article. It should be, as you said "two high-rises" and not "a two high-rises".